# when listing multiple filenames with os.walk, why can I not call each file name via a list index?

Tags: python, list, os.walk

My apologies if this has been asked and answered - I have searched thoroughly but cannot seem to find a clear explanation for behaviour I am seeing, and I'm very new to programming and python.

When I run the following code:

```
import os
directory = "J:"
extension = "pdf"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith("." + extension):
            print(filename)
```

It produces the following:

```
Bristol.Investments.Ltd.y16m03.INVOICE.pdf
Bristol.Investments.Ltd.y16m04.INVOICE.pdf
Bristol.Investments.Ltd.y16m05.INVOICE.pdf
James.Cunningham.2017.PAID.pdf
random.test.file.pdf
```

Now, if I were to change this to end in

```
print(filename[2])
```

I would expect it to print the third line like so:

```
Bristol.Investments.Ltd.y16m05.INVOICE.pdf
```

Instead I get the third letter from each line thus:

```
i
i
i
m
n
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour?  According to Python documentation, os.walk yields dirpath, dirnames, filenames, where "filenames" is "a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath" - but I guess I don't understand lists or how to access data within them properly.

If someone could explain why I am seeing this behaviour, and/or how to call the full file name out of the list of filenames, I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: You are looping over the filenames, therefore for each filename you are selecting the 3rd array element in the string which is the file name

Comment: e.g. each filename is a string, which is an array of characters, therefore your loop is looking at each filename, and selecting the 3rd element in the array of characters of that filename

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://realpython.com/python-strings/#StringIndexing

Comment: Yes, I was misunderstanding the workflow logic - I didn't realize the 'for' loop was still in play when making the call to print - thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sjdm already said in the comments, the problem is that you are accessing 3rd element of the `filename` string (which is a character) and not the 3rd element in the list of files.

To solve this I suggest to store all filenames in a list:

```
import os
directory = "J:"
extension = "pdf"

pdf_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith("." + extension):
            print(filename)
            pdf_files.append(filename)

print(pdf_files)  # print all collected files
print(pdf_files[2]) # print third collected file
```

Comment: Yes, I understand now - I have marked your answer as correct, and thank you for offering a solution to the problem along with the explanation!